# android studio build .9.png format error

Tags: android, android-studio

This is the error log:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':MobileSafe2:mergeDebugResources'.
Crunching Cruncher call_locate_blue.9.png failed, see logs
```

But when I turn the `.9.png` extension into `.png`, the error will disappear, I don't know why it happens.

This is the code :

```
    public void myToast(String address) {
        View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.address_show, null);
        view.setBackgroundResource(**R.drawable.call_locate_blue**);

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_address);
        textView.setText(address);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();

        params.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
        params.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;

        params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
        params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
        params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;
        wm.addView(view, params);
    }​
```

This is in Android Studio [image]

The error infomation:
[image]

I have got to fix '.9.png' into '.png', then it can work, but the picture will be distorted

Comment: what's your android build tools version? Have you tried Build->Clean?

Comment: Is your 9 patch well formed? Can you show it?

Comment: show your 9 patch img snap

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt 9patch. Check the edge pixels they need to be 100% alpha or 100% black

Comment: @agamov yes ,I have tried is,but don't work

Comment: @Der Golem but i don't know how to show it?i don't have the rights to upload a picture

Comment: @Blundell but it can work in Eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can see, you didn't put the `9 patch markers`.
These ones are needed to turn a **png** into a **9.png** (properly said a **9 patch**).

Without those markers, it will be a normal image - but the IDE expects something else, because the extension tells "Hey, I'm a 9 patch: treat me properly".

So to speak, it's like if you buy a lemonade, but you find an apple juice inside.

Here you'll find a nice tutorial on 9 patches: http://blog.booleanbites.com/2012/11/android-how-to-use-9-patch-png.html

Comment: @Shubham Try now - I provided a different link.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a little editing on the .9.png image file so that Android Studio can recognize that it is a 9 patch file .
I just do it like above and it works for me .

Comment: rename the 9 patch file .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had to first open the image in Android Studio and set the bounds of the image to be stretched. There needs to be a line on the edge of the image telling it how to be stretched. In Android studio they made this easy to adjust. If you click the show content box, You can see how your image is going to be stretched. For me this was SUPER useful in making chat bubbles.

Answer (score 0):

Try refactoring the file and rename to filename.9.png