# Gradle build or clean not working just after installing Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have just installed android studio on Ubuntu 14.04 and created a blank activity just for testing out. Now whenever i try to build the project the following error happens,

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Crunching Cruncher abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png failed, see logs
```

Now somewhere i found out that cleaning the project or restarting android studio will solve this problem but whenever i try to clean project the gradle taking long time and got stuck. I used android studio before but never encountered this kind of problem.

please any kind of help would be appreciated!!

Comment: check out **abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png** is png or jpg and if it is not in use just remove it.check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420706/android-studio-build-9-png-format-error

Comment: That's the thing!!!!! I have not added any images in the project as i mentioned it is a simple blank activity.....

Comment: @AmirZiarati But there's no image in this project other than ic_launcher!!!

Comment: abc_switch_track_mtrl_alpha.9.png is an support V7 library image resource. Please verify whether support library properly added in build.gradle or not

Comment: @ pokuri support library added like this compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1' do i need to add something else??

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `build` folders from `project root directory` and the `app` directory. The project should build fine after that.

Comment: i deleted the build folder as you said, but now gradle build just stuck for a long time!!

Comment: it will take a little longer for the first build after deleting those folder. That is because it will download the dependencies you may have in the project. After that it should be like before.